# round() mode ROUND_HALF_DOWN with PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, mode, rounding

I need to simulate ROUND_HALF_DOWN mode in PHP 5.2.17 - I cannot upgrade the server's PHP version. Any ideas how to achieve this?

The basic idea is that 1.895 becomes 1.89, not 1.90 like it usually does with round().

EDIT: 
This function seems to do the trick:

```
function nav_round($v, $prec = 2) {
    // Seems to fix a bug with the ceil function
    $v = explode('.',$v);
    $v = implode('.',$v);
    // The actual calculation
    $v = $v * pow(10,$prec) - 0.5;
    $a = ceil($v) * pow(10,-$prec);
    return number_format( $a, 2, '.', '' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take off 0.5^p where p is the precision and then use ceiling:

```php
<?php

function round_half_down($v, $prec) {
  $v = $v * pow(10,$prec) - 0.5;
  return ceil($v) * pow(10,-$prec);
}


print round_half_down(9.5,0) . "\n";
print round_half_down(9.05,0) . "\n";
print round_half_down(9.051,0) . "\n";
print round_half_down(9.05,1) . "\n";
print round_half_down(9.051,1) . "\n";
print round_half_down(9.055,2) . "\n";
print round_half_down(1.896,2) . "\n";

?>
```

yields:

```
$ php test.php 
9
9
9
9
9.1
9.05
1.9
```

You'll note that for any number x <= p <= x.5, we get ceiling(p - 0.5) = x, and for all x+1 => p > x.5, we get ceiling(p - 0.5) = x+1. This should be exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to work, but I need to do some real-life testing as it yields different results than Joseph's function in some cases.

Comment: Alright, it seems that this function pretty much does what I need, however, for some weird reason, sometimes it would round 1.825 up to 1.83. It seems to be a bug with PHP - when the number provided is a result of a calculation (for example, 1.326 - 0.001), it rounds it up to 1.83. When the number is provided as a string (without any calculations done with it before, it works OK. I fixed it by adding these lines in the beginning of the function:
`$v = explode('.',$v); $v = implode('.',$v);`

Comment: That sounds like it might be sound kind of floating point rounding error? Perhaps open another question with that :)?

Comment: Be careful since this solution doesn't always work! See code here: http://codepad.org/RbLilucR . The same code with the answer given by Joseph works (see comment under his answer).

Answer (score 6):

You can cheat by simply converting to a string and back:

```
$num = 1.895;

$num = (string) $num;

if (substr($num, -1) == 5) $num = substr($num, 0, -1) . '4';

$num = round(floatval($num), 2);
```

**EDIT:**

Here you have it in function form:

```
echo round_half_down(25.2568425, 6); // 25.256842

function round_half_down($num, $precision = 0)
{
    $num = (string) $num;
    $num = explode('.', $num);
    $num[1] = substr($num[1], 0, $precision + 1);
    $num = implode('.', $num);

    if (substr($num, -1) == 5)
        $num = substr($num, 0, -1) . '4';

    return round(floatval($num), $precision);
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not? Try it yourself!

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work. However I need to test it with my app with real-life cases to see if it always gives me the expected result.

Comment: Hey, in some cases, the rounding was wrong. For example, a number like this: 25.27518 rounded down to 25.25, when it should round to 25.26

Comment: @ragulka What precision did you round that with? If 2, then it should be 25.27, not 25.26

Comment: This one works better than the answer marked as correct: http://codepad.org/h6FBJaWF

Comment: I guess I was wrong... this one doesn't work either: http://codepad.org/SoFBe0xk . $num = explode('.', $num); should be changed to $num = explode('.', $num."0"); to work in this situations.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the easiest method for this prior to PHP 5.3 is to subtract 1 from the number following the last number in the required precision. So if you have precision 2 and want 1.995 to become 1.99 just subtract .001 from the number and round. This will always return a correct round except that the half value will round down rather than up.

Example1:

```
$num = 1.835;
$num = $num - .001; // new number is 1.834
$num = round($num,2);
echo $num;
```

The value after rounding is now 1.83

For another precision you just adjust where you subtract the 1 from.

Example2:

```
$num = 3.4895;
$num = $num - .0001; // new number is 3.4894
$num = round($num, 3);
echo $num;
```

The value after rounding is now 3.489

If you want a function to handle the work the following function does that.

```
function round_half_down($num,$precision)
{ 
    $offset = '0.';
    for($i=0; $i < $precision; $i++)
    {
        $offset = $offset.'0';
    }

    $offset =  floatval($offset.'1');
    $num = $num - $offset;
    $num = round($num, $precision);

    return $num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the preg_replace for this:

```
$string = '1.895';
$pattern = '/(\d+).(\d+)/e';
$replacement = "'\\1'.'.'.((substr($string, -1) > 5) ?  (substr('\\2',0,2) + 1)  :  substr('\\2',0,2))";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: This however will just truncate the number at 2 decimal places, while we want for example 1.896 to be rounded up to 1.90