# PHP round and PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP related issue

Tags: php

I have a number string with the following number :

```
$str=14.5;
```

I want to half up this value so that I get

```
15
```

I have tried this code

```
 echo round($str,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

But It doesn't work and I am getting errors :

```
 Use of undefined constants "PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP" , "Wrong parameter count for round"
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce it.](http://3v4l.org/0Pd8k) What PHP version do you have and what is the exact error message which you get?

Comment: Isn't round half* up the default?

Comment: @Rizier123 my php version is 5.3

Comment: Does simply round($str) work? Rest of the parameters seem to be defaults.

Comment: round() function is working fine ,if i use PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP contstants inside it then it returns error..

Comment: @Starkeen your version of PHP does not support the mode parameter, if you need different rounding modes you will need to use a custom function. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 5.3.0 the mode parameter was introduced. The errors suggest you are using an older version and are [replicated here in older versions](http://3v4l.org/JSgrR#v430).

However, in older versions `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` is the default, so you shouldn't have an issue. Just use `round($str, 0)`.

If you need to use different modes and must use version <5.3.0 there are other questions on the matter:

[round() mode ROUND_HALF_DOWN with PHP 5.2.17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103233/round-mode-round-half-down-with-php-5-2-17)